# Who came up with the term "complete spatial randomness?"

Tags: references, spatial, point-process, history

I've seen the term "[complete spatial randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_spatial_randomness)" widely used in literature but can't figure out who was the first to coin it. Who originated it, and is there a paper it can be cited to?

Comment: This question strikes me as off-topic, because it's not statistical in nature (not seeking statistical advice).  This seems to be a very basic research skill that you should have if you're writing research papers.  Surely, one of the hits on a [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Complete+Spatial+Randomness%22) would lead you to the answer that you seek...

Comment: I think it is statistical in nature. CSR is a statistical term, and knowing who came up with it and when reflects on the methodology used to calculate and analyze point patterns. It is also a matter of whether this is the term to use when describing point pattern that is random. The literature I came across so far did not have a reference as to who coined the term. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing the question somewhat. Reference requests are on-topic on this site, indeed we have a [tag:references].tag, and rephrasing the question in this way seems to consistent with what you want. (Feel free to revert my changes if you think they're unhelpful. I removed the detail that "I need it for a paper", as that isn't particularly relevant on this site.)

Comment: Thanks, @Silverfish, I wasn't aware of the `references` tag.  You learn something new everyday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term appears in

Diggle, P.J., Besag, J. & Gleaves, J.T. 1976. Statistical analysis of spatial point patterns by means of distance methods. *Biometrics* 32: 659–667. http://doi.org/10.2307/2529754

Besag, J. & Diggle, P.J. 1977. Simple Monte Carlo tests for spatial pattern. *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society Series C (applied Statistics)* 26: 327–333. http://doi.org/10.2307/2346974

and in several other papers from the middle 1970s on.